# how to convert Julian date (ordinal date) in Java

Tags: java, julian-date, date

Requirement : get the date in [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Terminology) format ([ordinal date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date)), compare it with current date, get the month and year out of it.

Convert it with output format.

Input format: yydddd
Output format: yymm

JDK 8

One way I can do is using date :

```
Date myDateWrong = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddd").parse("2020366");
```

Any cleaner way ?

Comment: Do not lnger use the old `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use the newer `java.time.*`API

Comment: You have to format the date to your output format. At the moment you only parse it to a date object

Comment: Does this help? [How to convert Julian to Date in Java for format of “yyDHH”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439571/how-to-convert-julian-to-date-in-java-for-format-of-yydhh)

Comment: looking for `java.time.*` solution which can parse yyyyddd format

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: When you mean a day-of-year, I suggest you use the term [*ordinal date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date). The term [*Julian date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is ambiguous, as it can refer to pre-Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

> looking for java.time.* solution which can parse yyyyddd format

That’s what I recommend too.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayOfYearFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuDDD");
    DateTimeFormatter yearMonthFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuMM");

    String yyyydddString = "2020366";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(yyyydddString, dayOfYearFormatter);
    String output = date.format(yearMonthFormatter);

    System.out.println(output);
```

Output is:

> 2012

So year 2020 month 12.

### What went wrong in your code?

Whether you use the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`, lowercase `d` is for day *of month* and uppercase `D` is for day *of year*. Why it worked with `SimpleDateFormat` anyway was because that class confusingly defaults month to January if no month is given. So your date was parsed into the 366th day of January. What?! That’s right, one more confusing trait of `SimpleDateFormat`, with default settings it happily parses non-existent dates. When there are only 31 days in January, it just extrapolates into the following months and ends up at December 31, the day you had intended. `SimpleDateFormat` is so full of nasty surprises like these. I recommend you never ever use that class again.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.