# Filter out the elements that Start with given 4 digit and store them into a List

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I would like to get the numbers that start with `2003` (`2003001` and `2003002`) and put them into another list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] num = {"2012001", "2003001", "2003002"};

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String actualList : num) {
        list.add(actualList);
    }
}
```

Comment: [String.startsWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: Are those dates? Looks to me like day 001 of year 2012 and so forth. In that case handle them as `LocalDate` objects, not as strings. And use `LocalDate.getYear()` to get the year (equal to the first 4 digits of your example strings). See for example [how to convert Julian date (ordinal date) in Java \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494889/how-to-convert-julian-date-ordinal-date-in-java).

Comment: Actually, year and the registered number. Example people born in 2012. The first one to register who was born in 2012 is 2012-001 then the second one to register is 2012-002 and so on. I am actually making an ID number on firebase using the date they were born.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In that case I would probably start out by designing a class to hold the number (or the person, depending) and being responsible for returning the birth year (as a `Year` object and/or as an `int`). Strings may seem versatile enough but really are unsuited for holding structured data like these.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the startsWith() method:

```
String[] num = {"2012001", "2003001", "2003002"};

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (String number : num) {
    if (number.startsWith("2003")) {
        list.add(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just remember the startsWith. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Adixe iterative solution, you could concisely achieve that also with streams by streaming the array, filtering for the elements starting with `2003` and the collecting the remaining elements with the terminal operation `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

```
String[] num = {"2012001", "2003001", "2003002"};
List<String> listNums = Arrays.stream(num)
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("2003"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As *@Ole V.V.* has pointed out in the comments, it seems like strings in your *array* are comprised of the **year** like `2012` and the ***day of the year*** like `001`.

If so, it would be match more convenient to convert this data into `LocalDate` than operating with it as if it's a plain string.

To parse these row strings into `LocalDate` you need to create a `DateTimeFormatter` using the static method [`ofPattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-).

A string pattern that corresponds to the sample data will be the following:

```
yyyyDDD
```

`y` - stands for year;

`D` - day of the year.

*For more information* [*see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

So to filter out dates having a *particular year*, firstly we need to parse every string using [`LocalDate.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) by passing the string and the *formatter* as arguments, and then extract *year* from each *date* by applying `getYear()`:

```
String [] num = {"2012001", "2003001", "2003002"};
        
int targetYear = 2003;
    
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyDDD");
        
List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.stream(num)
    .map(date -> LocalDate.parse(date, formatter)) 
    .filter(date -> date.getYear() == targetYear)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(dates);
```

*Output:*

```
[2003-01-01, 2003-01-02]
```